# Concatenate strings in Power BI with Query editor

Tags: powerbi, concatenation

I trying to make function with Advanced Query editor. I make simple function and that function work well.Below you can see how is look like that code:

```
(page as number) as table =>

let 
        Source = Web.BrowserContents("https://www.neptun.mk/pocetna/categories/TV_AUDIO_VIDEO/televizori.nspx?items=100&page=" & Number.ToText(page)),
        #"Extracted Table From Html" = Html.Table(Source, {{"Column1", ".product-list-item__content\-\-title"}, {"Column2", ".HappyCard"}, {"Column3", ".newPriceModel"}, {"Column4", "[width=""192""]", each [Attributes][src]?}}, [RowSelector=".product-list-item-grid"]),
        #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Extracted Table From Html",{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}, {"Column4", type text}}),
        #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each "https://www.neptun.mk"),
        #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Custom", "Column4"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
        #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Merged Columns", "Column2", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Column2.1", "Column2.2", "Column2.3", "Column2.4"}),
        #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column2.1", type text}, {"Column2.2", type text}, {"Column2.3", Int64.Type}, {"Column2.4", type text}}),
        #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Column3", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Column3.1", "Column3.2", "Column3.3", "Column3.4"}),
        #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"Column3.1", type text}, {"Column3.2", type text}, {"Column3.3", Int64.Type}, {"Column3.4", type text}}),
        #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type2",{"Column1", "Column2.3", "Column3.3", "Merged"}),
        #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Other Columns",{{"Column1", "ImageURL"}, {"Column2.3", "RegularPrice"}, {"Column3.3", "DiscountedPrice"}, {"Merged", "Title"}})
    in
        #"Renamed Columns"
```

Most important part of this piece of code is third line which begin with `Source =

```
Web.BrowserContents("https://www.neptun.mk/pocetna/categories/TV_AUDIO_VIDEO/televizori.nspx?items=100&page=" & Number.ToText(page)),` Actually here I want to add some additional string and concatenate with this piece of code.
```

In purpose to do that first I want to declare one more variable which is call items

```
 (page as number) as table =>
    (items as number) as table =>
    let 
      Source = Web.BrowserContents("https://www.neptun.mk/pocetna/categories/TV_AUDIO_VIDEO/televizori.nspx?items=100&page=" & Number.ToText(page)),
```

But now I have problem how to concatenate variable items into below part of code before part `" & Number.ToText(page)`.I try with this line but is not work well:

```
 Source = Web.BrowserContents("https://www.neptun.mk/pocetna/categories/TV_AUDIO_VIDEO/televizori.nspx?items="& Number.ToText(items),page=" & Number.ToText(page)),
```

So can anybody help me how to fix this code and concatenate into this line of code ?